# Prevent tag wiki creation for tags without interest?

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

I sometimes have the impression that people are just adding a wiki blurb to a tag to add some reputation the easy way. The tags in question have no followers.

I don't feel comfortable with having dozens of tags that are almost the same and could be
put into some common tag. E.g. there is no need to have a tag per Android-view or widget.

I wonder if SO could just not allow to create the tag wiki if e.g. a tag has less then 5 followers or less than x posts.

Otherwise: how do other moderators handle this?

Comment: Why would we want to prevent people from adding useful information? If the tag wiki is useless, there's already a system in place: reject it.

Comment: Tag wiki is for the purpose of clarifying the tag for the correct usage. And there are some tag that are a bit too specific (class in some standard library of the language) and doesn't have any follower but still has the purpose of categorization.

Comment: @nhahtdh Should this behavior be encouraged?

Comment: @HeikoRupp: Adding tag wiki is encouraged (just that some of them got approved too fast without considering how useful the tag wiki is). The small rep and the badge is not really a problem, though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> people are just adding a wiki blurb to a tag to add some reputation the easy way

Yep. So what? Lower-rep users might just be editing posts into shape to get the additional 2 rep as well. Does that do any harm? I would say no.

In either case, where a rep-gain is involved through some form of editing, we always have a review process accepting or rejecting the proposed edit. If the suggested edit is not good enough, it should simply be rejected.

I see no reason to limit this based on the number of people subscribed to a tag.

Based on your update you seem to be confusing the creation of tag wiki content with the creation of the tag itself. If you have a problem with specific tags existing altogether, then bring them up here on Meta. We do so all the time and if agreed upon those unnecessary tags are cleaned up. That is however another issue than the addition of tag wiki content.

Comment: I'd agree with this, if it weren't for a rather significant number of badge whores just accepting everything they can click on.  Peer review currently has some semi serious problems, and can't be relied on to keep the useless/bad edits out.

Comment: @cHao True, that's a significant issue which annoys me terribly. That does not imply we should put measures in place to prevent users from contributing though. That seems rather backward to me when we should actually be fixing/improving the review process.

Answer (score 1):

This would prevent legitimate new tags from being documented after being created.  I wouldn't have been able to create the wiki for the [gora](/questions/tagged/gora) tag on SO if this restriction had been in place.

Answer (score 1):

> I wonder if SO could just not allow to create the tag wiki if e.g. a tag has less then 5 followers or less than x posts.

The number of followers is not an indication of the usefulness of a tag, nor does it measure the need of having a tag wiki. The number of posts using a tag could be used to define when a tag needs a tag wiki, but I would not use it to prevent a user from creating a tag wiki: Tag wiki are necessary to guide the users about when using the tag; if users could be confused about using a tag, or the other, the tag wiki should be created when the tag is added.